# SKAction wait interval NOT consistent

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

I have a function that creates SpriteNode copies and move each copy along  a rectangle path at a specified interval. I have a problem with this interval that the action is executed at inconsistent interval making odd gaps between sprite nodes while action is running.

```
var items = [SKSpriteNode]();
let item = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship");

func createItem(scene: SKScene) {

    let square = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: -300, y: -150,  width: 700, height: 300));
    let follow = SKAction.follow(square.cgPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: false, duration: 5.0);

    for i in 0..<6 {

        if let itemCopy = item.copy() as? SKSpriteNode {
            itemCopy.position = CGPoint(x: -300, y: -150);
            items.append(itemCopy);
            scene.addChild(itemCopy);
            let otherWait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0, withRange: 2.0);
            let otherSequence = SKAction.sequence([otherWait, SKAction.repeatForever(follow)]);
                itemCopy.run(otherSequence);
            }
        }
}
```

My understanding is that I can't rely on `for loop` for timing and this issue could be caused by that. Is there a way to get around this with some kind of callback function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is not related to the for loop, but comes from that fact you're using `wait(forDuration:withRange:)`, and this is the intended behaviour. The documentation states:

> Creates an action that idles for a randomized period of time.

I think you're looking for the `wait(forDuration:)` method and it will work just fine :)

Comment: Thank you. The only issue with wait(forDuration:) is that all items will overlap on top of each other and look like only one is moving. So I needed an extra interval for each item to start moving at a different timing. Too bad it's for random period of time..

Comment: I got it to work by just using wait(forDuration:) and increment the duration in a loop. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad to hear that @SeongLee! :) Yep! Another solution would be to write your code inside the update() method, and keep track of the last dish added, if the delta time is > 2 sec for example, you add a new dish.